# Панель-окно WPF

Tags: wpf

В Visual Studio к примеру solution explorer да и вся их навигация похожа на панели, но они легко движутся с мышкой да и вообще открываются как окна. Как это работает? Что это за смесь контролов?

Comment: Ну такая себе смесь контролов.

Comment: Нет, вот прямо таких готовых контролов нет. Но на en.SO много ответов со ссылками: https://stackoverflow.com/q/571671/276994, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4211569/276994, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31524569/276994, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609291/276994 и т. п.

Comment: Почитайте Адама Натана, у него есть пример создания подобного приложения

Comment: Вот готовый контрол: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock